# Outlook rules don't run automatically

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, desktop

I have a set of "rules" implemented on Outlook Desktop.

But each time I receive a message that matches one of them, it does nothing.

I have to run the rules manually to make them work.

What setting should I search and activate to let them run automatically?

---

And just to defuse some remarks, I did check "Turn on this rule" and uncheck "Do not execute other rules".
As described here [Microsoft help on this subject](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-rule-i-created-does-not-work-1a89069c-6b54-4ac1-b4c3-8027f60196d1).

Comment: Do all the rules you created not work? What about creating the rule on web mail?

Comment: Is there any update?

Comment: Yes, I should post a response.
At its creation, a rule has a checkbox like "Activate this rule" unchecked by default, as if it was normal to create something to not use it. It's directly during the wizard part, last page.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague without examples, or knowing what your existing setup is, but one possible solution, it might not work for you, is if another rule further up the list has 'do not execute other rules'

I would first try disabling all other rules, save, then send yourself an email from another account (not the account receiving the email) that should trigger the email rule.  If that works, check all your other rules.